# This maybe a bug of llvm-gcc for ios-armv7, that I can't explain

Tags: ios, c, gcc, arm

```
    the following code works fine on linux-x86, darwin-x86, but not for ios-armv7.

    the right output should be: 
        m[0]: 0.500000, v: 0.500000
        m[1]: 0.500000, v: 0.500000
        m[2]: 0.500000, v: 0.500000
        m[3]: 0.500000, v: 0.500000
        m[4]: 0.500000, v: 0.500000

    but I found the wrong output:
        m[0]: 0.500000, v: 0.500000
        m[1]: 0.500000, v: 0.000000
        m[2]: 0.500000, v: 0.000000
        m[3]: 0.500000, v: 0.000000
        m[4]: 0.500000, v: 0.000000

    I also found the stange when it's built for ios-armv7:

    [a] remove function 'func', move the function body to 'main' function, it works fine
    [b] declare the array 'm[5]' as 'double m[5]', it works fine
    [c] set the variable 'v' as 'v = 0.5 or v = sqrt(2.0f/8)', it works fine
    [d] if the gcc optimize option is '-O0', it works fine, but when it's '-O1 or -O2', wrong output occurs


    My iPad1 was cracked, so I can cross-compile a executable on my MacBook Air, and 'scp' the executable to iPad1 and run it. The following is details:

    1. cross-compile a executable on Mac:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc -O1 -Wall -arch armv7 -mcpu=cortex-a8 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/usr/include -D__IPHONE_OS__ -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 foo.c

    2. 'scp' the executable to iPad
    scp a.out mobile@192.168.1.106:~

    3. 'ssh' to iPad
    ssh mobile@192.168.1.106 #the default password is 'alpine'

    4. run a.out on iPad
    ./a.out
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int
func(int n) /* [a] */
{
    int i;
    float m[5]; /* [b] */
    double v;

    v = sqrt(2.0f/n); /* [c] */

    for(i=0;i<5;++i) {
        m[i]=v;
        printf("m[%d]: %f, v: %f\n", i, m[i], v);
    }

    return 0;
}


int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return func(8);
}
```

You can also find the whole code on https://gist.github.com/ashun/5992120

The following is the assembly. you can find the difference with the help of command 'vim -d'

1. assembly of the previous code, declare the array 'm[5]' as 'double m[5]'

```
        .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
        .section    __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
        .section    __TEXT,__const_coal,coalesced
        .section    __TEXT,__picsymbolstub4,symbol_stubs,none,16
        .section    __TEXT,__StaticInit,regular,pure_instructions
        .syntax unified
        .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
        .globl  _func
        .align  2
        .code   16
        .thumb_func _func
    _func:
        push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
        add r7, sp, #12
        str r8, [sp, #-4]!
        sub sp, #8
        vmov.f32    s0, #2.000000e+00
        movw    r8, :lower16:(L_.str-(LPC0_0+4))
        vmov    s2, r0
        movt    r8, :upper16:(L_.str-(LPC0_0+4))
        vcvt.f32.s32    d1, d1
    LPC0_0:
        add r8, pc
        movs    r4, #0
        vdiv.f32    s0, s0, s2
        vsqrt.f32   s0, s0
        vcvt.f64.f32    d16, s0
        vmov    r5, r6, d16
    LBB0_1:
        mov r1, r4
        mov r0, r8
        mov r2, r5
        mov r3, r6
        vstr.64 d16, [sp]
        adds    r4, #1
        blx _printf
        cmp r4, #5
        bne LBB0_1
        movs    r0, #0
        add sp, #8
        ldr r8, [sp], #4
        pop {r4, r5, r6, r7, pc}

        .globl  _main
        .align  2
        .code   16
        .thumb_func _main
    _main:
        push    {r7, lr}
        mov r7, sp
        movs    r0, #8
        bl  _func
        movs    r0, #0
        pop {r7, pc}

        .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
    L_.str:
        .asciz   "m[%d]: %f, v: %f\n"


    .subsections_via_symbols
```

1. assembly of the previous code, declare the array 'm[5]' as 'double m[5]'

```
        .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
        .section    __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
        .section    __TEXT,__const_coal,coalesced
        .section    __TEXT,__picsymbolstub4,symbol_stubs,none,16
        .section    __TEXT,__StaticInit,regular,pure_instructions
        .syntax unified
        .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
        .globl  _func
        .align  2
        .code   16
        .thumb_func _func
    _func:
        push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
        add r7, sp, #12
        str r8, [sp, #-4]!
        **vpush {d8}**
        sub sp, #8
        vmov.f32    s0, #2.000000e+00
        movw    r8, :lower16:(L_.str-(LPC0_0+4))
        vmov    s2, r0
        movt    r8, :upper16:(L_.str-(LPC0_0+4))
        vcvt.f32.s32    d1, d1
    LPC0_0:
        add r8, pc
        movs    r4, #0
        vdiv.f32    s0, s0, s2
        vcvt.f64.f32    d16, s0
        vsqrt.f64   d8, d16
        vmov    r5, r6, d8
    LBB0_1:
        mov r1, r4
        mov r0, r8
        mov r2, r5
        mov r3, r6
        vstr.64 d8, [sp]
        adds    r4, #1
        blx _printf
        cmp r4, #5
        bne LBB0_1
        movs    r0, #0
        add sp, #8
        vpop    {d8}
        ldr r8, [sp], #4
        pop {r4, r5, r6, r7, pc}

        .globl  _main
        .align  2
        .code   16
        .thumb_func _main
    _main:
        push    {r7, lr}
        mov r7, sp
        movs    r0, #8
        bl  _func
        movs    r0, #0
        pop {r7, pc}

        .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
    L_.str:
        .asciz   "m[%d]: %f, v: %f\n"


    .subsections_via_symbols
```

Comment: That does look like a bug in the compiler indeed. Maybe you can add the generated assembly of `func` for the `-O1` case. The loop may be unrolled in which case replacing `5` by `2` may be more appropriate, if that still reproduces the bug.

Comment: Thanks, I add the assembly of the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear which assembly goes wrong as both are marked as 'declare the array `m[5]` as `double m[5]`' and unfortunately I don't have the hardware nor the cross-compiler to reproduce your problem.

Remarkably the loops in both assembly codes are very similar. The only difference being that `v` is located in `d16` in the first and in `d8` in the second. The `v` that is passed to the `printf` is located in `(r5,r6)` in both loops and correctly copied to `(r2,r3)` before calling `printf`. For variadic functions the floating point registers shall not be used to pass parameters, contrary to non-variadic functions. Thus both loops look correct.

The only explanation I can think of is a mismatch in the ABI used for the compiled code and the ABI of the library containing `printf`. Especially considering that the compiled code comes from a cross compiler and I'm assuming the `printf` comes from a dynamic library on the system. As the `printf` is called conforming to the EABI for ARM, I think the bug is in the `printf` of the library.

If your cross compiler allows static linking, you may try that as you will be using a library that corresponds with the compiler. Of course the application becomes bigger, but it could at least confirm suspicion on the implementation of the `printf`. You may want to check if the library is compiled with an EABI complying compiler. If you can step through the `printf` on a debugger on the iPad, then you should be able to determine where the `printf` is taking its floating point parameter from. It should take it from `(r2,r3)`.

Unfortunately I can not give a conclusive answer, but I hope my pointers for further investigation are helpful.